# Eclipse as an cross platform IDE for C++ code on Linux and Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eclipse, compiler-construction

I consider an option to use Eclipse as an cross platform IDE for C++ code on Linux and Windows.

1. Is it possible to set Eclipse to compile code with Visual Studio C++ 
   (don't think it's relevant but Eclipse project files will be created by cmake).
2. Is it possible to debug from Eclipse application compiled by VS C++ compiler?
3. Is it possible to debug on Linux from Eclipse application compiled by g++?
4. What C++ IDE you prefer for Linux - Eclipse, Kdevelop or there're other alternatives?

Thanks
Dima

Answer (score 2):

1. No as far as I know. The alternative would be [wascana project](http://wascana.sourceforge.net/). Now that the new version of [MinGw](http://www.mingw.org/) has been released and it uses gcc.4.4 I think that wascana will be able to compete against Visual Studio, but we still have to wait to the next release of wascana.
2. No as far as I know. Again [wascana](http://wascana.sourceforge.net/) could be an alternative.
3. Sure, try **cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"**, build your project and create a debug configuration with eclipse. I've done it before with no problems at all.
4. I move from Emacs to Eclipse. I remember I evaluated Kdevelop but I discarded it for reasons unconnected to Kdevelop's quality itself. So I cannot give you my opinion. Another C++ crossplatform IDE is [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/), but I have never used it.

Answer (score 1):

I do some C++ with Qt cross-platform development in Linux, Windows and Mac and I found Eclipse to be too heavy an environment to work with. As an IDE I preferred [Qt Creator](http://www.qtsoftware.com/products/developer-tools).